# What are the sufficient conditions for quotient of Hausdorff space to again be a Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology

Initial question in the paper was **Is the quotient of Hausdorff space always Hausdorff?**.

My attempt so far: I have been able to find a counter example:

Let $\Bbb Z$/2 act on $\Bbb R$×{0} ∪ $\Bbb R$×{1} by *g* ⋅ (t,0) = (t,1) and *g* ⋅ (t,1) = (t,0) if t ≠ 0 and *g* ⋅ (0,0) = (0,0) and *g* ⋅ (1,1) = 1. Then the quotient space is the line with two origins which is not Hausdorff.

So I understand that initial question is false. I am not particularly happy about the group theoretic nature of the counter example. Which leads me to ask *what are the sufficient conditions such that quotient of Hausdorff would be Hausdorff.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give you a condition that occurs quite naturally and does not deal with groups:

Let $X$ be a hausdorff space and let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $X$. Suppose that the quotient map $\eta \colon X \rightarrow X/{\sim}$ is open. Then $X/{\sim}$ is hausdorff iff $R \subset X \times X$ is closed, where $R$ is the set that defines $\sim$.